# Please add Stockholm as a featured city

Tags: feature-request, jobs

In my opinion, Stockholm should be one of the featured cites on [careers.stackoverflow.com/cites](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities), considering Sweden has the top number of Stack Overflow users per capita ([REF](http://venturebeat.com/2015/04/05/data-best-programming-talent-in-the-world-is-not-in-california/)). Stockholm features, DICE, Paradox games, ... and has a mini silicon valley called Kista.

So, please add it to the list of featured cities.

Comment: I guess there could be added a lot more places. I see Amsterdam and Utrecht in the Netherlands, while Eindhoven is one of the largest tech centers here. I think it is still in beta, so subject to change.